# C# - EF 6 Abstract Navigation Property

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, abstract-class, poco

I have the following *abstract* classes:

**NotaFiscal:**

```
public abstract partial class NotaFiscal
{   
    public virtual ICollection<NotaFiscalItem> NotaFiscalItens { get; set; }
}
```

**NotaFiscalItem:**

```
public abstract class NotaFiscalItem
{   
    ...
}
```

From which will be generated the *concrete* classes:

**NotaFiscalEntrada:**

```
public class NotaFiscalEntrada : NotaFiscal
{   
    public int NotaFiscalEntradaId { get; set; }
}
```

**NotaFiscalEntradaItem:**

```
public class NotaFiscalEntradaItem : NotaFiscalItem
{   
    public int NotaFiscalEntradaItemId { get; set; }
}
```

**The question:**
The navigation property in the abstract class *NotaFiscal* is an collection of abstract objects, is there a way to navigate in the concrete class *NotaFiscalEntrada* to the objects in the collection, which will be concrete too - *NotaFiscalEntradaItem*? Is there a way to tell that in the concrete class *NotaFiscalEntrada* the ICollection of NotaFiscalItem will be the NotaFiscalEntradaItem and EF will understand this and navigate to it?

I gotta use it this way because the intelligence of the collection (LINQ queries, sum...etc..) is all in the abstract class, and others classes like *NotaFiscalSaida* and *NotaFiscalItemSaida* will be created from the abstract classes. Each one will be a table in the DB.

I'm using Code First, POCO, EF 6.1 and TPC mapping.

Comment: What is the name of the property with `ICollection<NotaFiscalItem>`?

Comment: Oops, my mistake, the name is NotaFiscalItens. Edited the post. Sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Entity Framework does not support Generic Entities, but it does support Entities that are *inheriting* generic classes

Try to change your abstract `NotaFiscal` class to have a generic parameter to represent each `NotaFiscalItem`:

```
public abstract class NotaFiscal<T> where T : NotaFiscalItem
{
    public abstract ICollection<T> NotaFiscalItems { get; set; }
}
```

Then in your concrete classe:

```
public class NotaFiscalEntrada : NotaFiscal<NotaFiscalEntradaItem>
{
    public int NotaFiscalEntradaId { get; set; }

    public override ICollection<NotaFiscalEntradaItem> NotaFiscalItems { get; set; }
}
```

This way, your concrete `NotaFiscal` types will be able to expose their concrete `NotaFiscalItem` collection using the `NotaFiscalItems` property of each.

Comment: Excellent! That's right! One question: I will be able to use lazy loading int it? Beacause it lacks the virtual modifier that activates it.

Comment: @AlexandreMurariJunior, `abstract` implies `virtual`, so the answer is yes. Also, strictly speaking, `virtual` does not 'activate' Lazy-Loading but *allows* it.

Comment: I understand, I forgot the override rule (`virtual` CAN override, `abstract` MUST override) all of them implies `virtual`. Thanks a lot. That was really helpful.